# How to skip callbacks with ClassName.update?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model "Person", and I am updating it through:

```
hash = {"id" => 1}
updatedHash = {"name" => "UPDATED_NAME"}

Person.update(hash["id"], updatedHash)
```

In my Person model, I have an callback when its updated:

```
after_commit :postUpdate, :on => :update
after_update :postUpdate #optionally I can have this, and exclude the above
```

How do I deactivate this callback if I'm using Person.update? (don't tell me to use update_column, or any of those methods since I can't change the way I'm updating).

I tried:

```
Person.skip_callback(:update, :after_commit)
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to do

```
Person.skip_callback(:update, :after_commit, :postUpdate)
```

Or whatever the name of the callback you want to skip is called.

As a side note. It is considered proper in ruby to use snake case and not camel case for variable and function names.

Comment: Is there any way to use this when the callback was assigned as a lambda?